# Ndk error Application target deprecated

Tags: android, android-ndk, deprecated

```
Error:(81) Android NDK: Application targets deprecated ABI(s): mips64 armeabi mips    
Error:(82) Android NDK: Support for these ABIs will be removed in a future NDK release.
```

This is my Application.mk file

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti
APP_CPPFLAGS := -fexceptions -frtti
APP_CPPFLAGS +=-std=c++11
APP_CPPFLAGS +=-fpermissive

APP_ABI=armeabi-v7a
```

Redirecting to setup-app.mk

```
_deprecated_abis := $(filter $(NDK_DEPRECATED_ABIS),$(NDK_APP_ABI))
ifneq ($(_deprecated_abis),)
    $(call __ndk_warning,Application targets deprecated ABI(s): $(_deprecated_abis))
    $(call __ndk_warning,Support for these ABIs will be removed in a future NDK release.)
endif
```

I downloaded the ndk through Android studio.

Answer (score 1):

If you run **ndk-build** via gradle, it ignores the `APP_ABI` in your **Application.mk**. In this case, your **build.gradle** should define **abiFilters**, e.g.

```
android {
   ndk {
       abiFilters "armeabi-v7a"
   }
}
```